# TS lint disallow leading underscore

Tags: typescript, tslint

There is a rule for disallow leading underscore?

I know only this rule, that allows these.

```
"variable-name": [true, "ban-keywords", "check-format", "allow-leading-underscore"]
```

Comment: Well, remove "allow-leading-underscore" from the array, and they won't be allowed anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There is a rule for disallow leading underscore

Enable `check-format` and *do not enable* `allow-leading-underscore` and it is disabled by default

## More

- docs : https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/variable-name/